# Carrierwave delete file from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, carrierwave

The title says everything. I currently have a model concern with which I'm setting if a model can have attachments or not using `include Attachable`. So far so good.

Then, when I display the list of files attached to a particular model, I'm adding a link to delete it such as :

```
DELETE /posts/:post_id/attachments/:id(.:format)      attachments#destroy
```

For that purpose, I created an `AttachmentsController` with a `destroy` method. So I have 2 problems here. The first, how can I delete a file from this controller using Carrierwave (for delete the file itself and the table record)?
Second, since my attachable behavior gonna be plug in several model :

```
DELETE /posts/:post_id/attachments/:id(.:format)      attachments#destroy
DELETE /users/:user_id/attachments/:id(.:format)      attachments#destroy
...
```

How can I do in my AttachmentsController to delete a file depending on the associated model dynamically?

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Sluggable

  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :file, AttachmentUploader

  validates :name, presence: true, if: :file?
  validates :file, presence: true, if: :name?
end

class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def destroy
    // Don't know how to remove that file
    redirect_to :back
  rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Hope I was clear.

Thanks

**EDIT :**
Ok I create a tweak on the params hash in order to get the associated object dynamically within `AttachmentsController` :

```
private
  def get_attachable_model
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        model = name.match(/([^\/.]*)_id$/)
        return model[1].classify.constantize
      end
    end
    nil
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally found a solution myself. Here is my `destroy` method from `AttachmentsController` :

```
def destroy
  model, param = get_attachable_instance
  model_attach = model.find_by slug: params[param.to_sym]
  file         = model_attach.attachments.find_by slug: params[:id]
  file.destroy

  redirect_to :back
rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Not sure if it's the best way to go, but it does works